# What's the difference between "transmit rate" and "link speed"?

Tags: wifi, airport

On my MacBook Pro, System Information (or `airport` or option-clicking on the wifi status icon) reports a "transmit rate" of 176

[image]

while Networt Utility reports a "link speed" of 289

[image]

What's the difference between these two parameters?

Comment: Don't say its 113.

Comment: That's funny :) you get a + point from me for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already see the answer in your screen shot.

The maximum possible rate is 289.

The current transmit rate is 176.

Comment: Doh! I see! How did I miss that!

Comment: Sorry, please post that as your next question :)